# New to python, trying to write and read pickle file on hosted server

Tags: python-3.x, server, pickle, hosted

Just going through basic python3 on Head First book. Trying to deploy code on hosted server. Most of the scripts are working on the cgi-bin as executable but the pickle file is not writing or reading. It works on my localhost. I've changed chmod permissions on So it must be with permissions, etc., what do I need to do on hosted server to make it work?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try SUDO on linux based server?

Comment: many thanks for your reply.. I've tried sudo but it's not recognised it. I'm trying something else for now but just wanted to thank you for your time.